# Why does a loop not ask for command line input every cycle in C++?

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I have a small program written in C++ that requests command line input for the user's grade. If the input is valid (i.e. a number between 0 and 100), a switch is called to print something out based on the user's grade, and then the program exits successfully.

If the user enters a *number* that isn't a valid grade, the program successfully loops back and asks for valid input until the user enters an appropriate grade.

However, if the user enters a String that isn't a number at all, such as "no", the loop infinitely requests a valid grade without ever stopping to take input, ultimately crashing the command line.

**The complete program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

cout << "\nEnter your grade: ";

int grade;

// Infinite input loop.
while(true) {
    // Is the String a valid grade?
    if(cin >> grade && grade >= 0 && grade <= 100) {
        switch(grade / 10) {
            case 10:
            case 9:
                cout << "A is for \"Awesome\"!";
                break;
            case 8:
                cout << "B is okay.";
                break;
            case 7:
                cout << "C isn't okay.";
                break;
            case 6:
                cout << "Bad luck.";
                break;
            case 5:
            case 4:
            case 3:
            case 2:
            case 1:
                cout << "Ouch!";
                break;
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
        break;
    } else {
        cout << "Please enter a valid grade: ";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the stream enters a failure state.  When the fail bit is set in the stream all operations will fail.  You need to call `clear()` on the stream to clear out the error flags and then you need to remove any extra input that could still be in the stream.  You can do that with

```
cin.clear(); // clear error flags
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You will need to include the `<limits>` header for this.